# why does write addSublayer twice to block screenshot in swift?

Tags: swift, calayer, uiwindow

I found an extension function to block screeenShot in iOS.
But I wounder to know why addSublayer twice.

> self.layer.superlayer?.addSublayer(textfield.layer)
> textfield.layer.sublayers?.last?.addSublayer(self.layer)

what's these code mean?
I can't figure out.
I need some explains to let me know how it works.
Thanks.

```
extension UIWindow {
    
    func makeSecure() {

        let textfield = UITextField()
        textfield.isSecureTextEntry = true
        self.addSubview(textfield)
        textfield.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        textfield.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor).isActive = true

        self.layer.superlayer?.addSublayer(textfield.layer)
        textfield.layer.sublayers?.last?.addSublayer(self.layer)
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method of preventing screenshots uses the unique behaviour of text fields with `isSecureTextEntry = true`. These text fields cannot be screenshotted. They appear black on screenshots.

This is why the code adds `self.layer` as a sublayer of the text field's last sublayer. The text field's last sublayer happens to be the layer that doesn't get screenshotted (though I don't think this is guaranteed by the documentation). By adding `self.layer` to this, the entire `self.layer` will not appear in screenshots.

Of course, we haven't actually added the text field's layer to the rest of the layer hierarchy yet, similar to the common mistake of creating a view, and then forgetting to `addSubview` to an existing view. At this point the text field is just some random thing in memory with nothing else knowing about it.

This is why we add the text field's layer as a sublayer of `self.layer.superlayer`. Now the system actually knows the secure text field exists and prevents screenshots.

Note that we can't add it to `self.layer`, because that would cause a cycle in the layers' relationships - `self.layer` would be a child of itself, and at the same time, a parent of itself. Also, by adding as a sibling of the window's layer (instead of a sublayer of the window's layer), it also doesn't appear on the screen.

FYI, the layer hierarchy looks like this in the end:

```
      the rest of the layer hierarchy
                     |
             self.layer.superlayer
                |         \
                |   textfield.layer
                |      /
                |     /
                |    /
                |   /
           self.layer     
                |
           your views
```

This diagram makes it look as if `self.layer` have two `superlayer`s when it actually doesn't. `self.layer.superlayer` doesn't change when `self.layer` is added as a sublayer of `textfield.layer`. The lines here are only showing the sublayer relationship - the layers on the bottom of the lines are sublayers of the layers on the top of the lines.

Comment: hi @Sweeper, 
Are self.layer on the left and self.layer on the right the same instance?

Comment: @JimmyLee Yes. Otherwise this wouldn't work, would it? :)

Comment: Thx, but I am also a bit confused.
So, according to this layer hierarchy, is the displayed screen showing the view on the right of 'your views'?
Is the 'your views' on the left covered?
Or is there another explanation?

Comment: @JimmyLee I have edited the answer so that `self.layer` appears only once. Does that make more sense? `self.layer` is not screenshotted because it is a sublayer of `textfield.layer`. And `textfield.layer` is not visible, because it is not a sublayer of `self.layer`.